# Data Cleaning in R - just get the numbers out of column

Tags: r, data-cleaning

i have crawled some car data and no i want to clean it to work with this data.
The Data Frame looks like this:

```
> head(cars_clean)
     car_name          car_prize     ps                km            kraftstoff  baujahr
     1 Volkswagen Lupo \n€ 399,-\n  \n37 kW (50 PS)\n \n215.000 km\n \nBenzin\n \n06/2004\n
     2      Opel Corsa \n€ 450,-\n  \n40 kW (54 PS)\n \n163.799 km\n \nBenzin\n \n01/2001\n
     3  Renault Megane \n€ 490,-\n  \n72 kW (98 PS)\n \n184.400 km\n \nBenzin\n \n07/2004\n
     4         Audi A3 \n€ 490,-\n \n92 kW (125 PS)\n \n222.000 km\n \nBenzin\n \n10/1999\n
     5      Opel Corsa \n€ 499,-\n  \n55 kW (75 PS)\n \n370.000 km\n \nDiesel\n \n03/2003\n
     6     Ford Fiesta \n€ 499,-\n  \n55 kW (75 PS)\n \n189.137 km\n \nBenzin\n \n07/2000\n
```

Now i want to clean for example the ps column:

```
> cars_clean$ps
    [1] "\n37 kW (50 PS)\n"   "\n40 kW (54 PS)\n"   "\n72 kW (98 PS)\n"  
    [4] "\n92 kW (125 PS)\n"  "\n55 kW (75 PS)\n"   "\n55 kW (75 PS)\n"  
    [7] "\n96 kW (131 PS)\n"  "\n55 kW (75 PS)\n"   "\n90 kW (122 PS)\n" 
    [10] "\n98 kW (133 PS)\n"  "\n74 kW (101 PS)\n"  "\n75 kW (102 PS)\n"
```

Out of this i only want to get the PS value in the brackets, so "50" for the first value.
How can i do this?

With the "car_prize" column i tried following, which has worked for me. But this solution doesn't work with the "ps" column:

```
clean_prize <- parse_number(cars_clean$car_prize)
```

This line got me just the digits in the "car_prize" column.

Thanks for your help! :)

Edit: i also want to convert the column "baujahr" (which represents the year the car was built) to a date format.
Just "as.Date(cars_clean$baujahr)" didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract via `str_extract`and lookaround:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=\\()\\d+(?= PS)")
[1] "50" "54" "98"
```

This picks out any number of `d`igits that are preceded to the left by `(`and followed to the right by  `PS`.

Data:

```
x <- c("\n37 kW (50 PS)\n","\n40 kW (54 PS)\n","\n72 kW (98 PS)\n")
```

Answer (score 3):

Base R method using `sub` :

```
x <- c("\n37 kW (50 PS)\n","\n40 kW (54 PS)\n","\n72 kW (98 PS)\n")
as.numeric(sub('.*?(\\d+)\\sPS).*', '\\1', x))
#[1] 50 54 98
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
readr::parse_number(str_remove(x, '[^(]*'))
#[1] 50 54 98
```

#### data

```
x <- c("\n37 kW (50 PS)\n","\n40 kW (54 PS)\n","\n72 kW (98 PS)\n")
```